# how to handle exceptions in a single place in nodejs and express

Tags: node.js, events, error-handling, express

In nodejs express to handle exceptions , check for err in callbacks as :

```
if(err!==null){
    next(new Error ('Erro Message')); 
}
```

Which in turn calls the express's error handler middleware .

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    if(!err) return next();
    console.log('<-------Error Occured ----->');
    res.send(500, JSON.stringify(err, ['stack', 'message']));
});
```

But to call invoke next(err) , I'm forced to pass around the reference for **next** across all the callback methods through all the layers . I find this a messy aproach . Is there a better way to handle exceptions and send a proper response using events or domains .

Answer (score 1):

You should always delegate the error in the routes / controllers to the error handler by calling next (so you can just deal with them in one place instead of having them scattered throughout your application).

Here's an example:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  db.findUser(req.params.userId, function(err, uid) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    /* ... */
  });
});

/* Your custom error handler */

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // always log the error here

  // send different response based on content type
  res.format({
    'text/plain': function(){
      res.status(500).send('500 - Internal Server Error');
    },

    'text/html': function(){
      res.status(500).send('<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>');
    },

    'application/json': function(){
      res.send({ error: 'internal_error' });
    }
  });
});
```

Note: You don't have to check for the `err` param in the error handler because it will always be present.

Also very important: always do `return next(err);` because you don't want the success code to be executed.

Both your code samples were flawed: in the first one you didn't use `return next(err)` and in the second one you have used `return next(err)`, so code that followed shouldn't be handling the error (because it will never get there in case there's an error), but instead it should have been the 'success' code.

Comment: My actual question was about a better way to handle exception rather than using express middleware. As my application has different layers I can't pass around the reference of next accross all the layers. Is domain or events a better choice.?

Comment: You don't need to pass around `next` everywhere in all layers, you can use callbacks for that. For example `Model.find(userId, cb)` can be called in the route handler and if you detect an error there you invoke `next`

Answer (score 0):

The error pages example from Express showsthe canonical way of handling errors:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/error-pages/index.js

```
// error-handling middleware, take the same form
// as regular middleware, however they require an
// arity of 4, aka the signature (err, req, res, next).
// when connect has an error, it will invoke ONLY error-handling
// middleware.

// If we were to next() here any remaining non-error-handling
// middleware would then be executed, or if we next(err) to
// continue passing the error, only error-handling middleware
// would remain being executed, however here
// we simply respond with an error page.
```